# Rails: how to insert unique value into the database without duplication?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to ruby on rails. i want to generate unique token for each client. i can generate unique token with SecureRandom.hex(6),but then i have to check wheter this value exists in the database and it is very time consuming if the database is very large. i can append the current time to secureadnom.hex(6) function but then again if the rails processes the two request at the same time then there is no guaranty of uniqueness.

Can someone tell me the best way to generate unique token without hitting query to database level.

Thanks,

Comment: Looks like you are trying to invent [UUID](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid). You can use MySQL's implementation or find one for ruby and use that.

Comment: @Vatev - I can use UUID but there is no guarantee of uniqueness. am i rght??

Comment: It is designed to be "the best way to generate unique token without hitting query to database level". It is extremely unlikely to to give you the same value twice: "A UUID is designed as a number that is globally unique in space and time. Two calls to UUID() are expected to generate two different values, even if these calls are performed on two separate computers that are not connected to each other."

Answer (score 1):

do this.

```
#attribute = [SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64, Time.now.to_i].join("")
```

for your attribute which you want to set. probability will be very less that one value will duplicate it self and to remove that you can add validation on that field.

```
validates_uniqueness_of :attribute
```

Comment: Just to be 100% sure, there also should be a unique index on the attribute column.

Answer (score 1):

To guarantee that the token generated is unique you can put a unique constraint on your index.
And then in your code you can handle the exception.

example

```
begin
#generate your code here and try to save it.
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => e
#If exception occurs then again repeat the same process for another hex code and save it.
end
```

Comment: This works fine . but i have to generate token without hitting query to the databases and token should not be more than 8 Digit